# I would like to use a function to clean up this code

Tags: python, function

[Link to image with code that is repetitive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1CRa.png)

I am only a beginner and not sure how to go about doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you have any helpful resources for learning this type of thing please do share. Apologies for not adhering to the usual format of most other posts on here.

Comment: Please send the code as Text in the Question. Not as Picture.

Comment: please go through how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
List_of_urls = ["https:...", "https:..."]

for i in range(len(List_of_urls):
  url = List_of_urls[i]
  request = request.get(url)
  request = request.json()
  ...
```

or

```
def do stuff(url):
   do each of those lines
```

and then run that function 5 times or in a loop

Answer (score 0):

If you perform the same operations based on an input url, simply put those steps in a function.

```py
def create_df(my_url):

    my_request = requests.get(my_url)
    my_request = my_request.json()
    my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_request['prices'])
    my_df.rename(columns = {0 : 'Date', 1 : 'Price'}, inplace=True)
    my_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['Date'], unit='ms')
    my_df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
    my_df.drop(['Date'], axis=1, inplace=True)

    return my_df

my_urls = [btc_url, eth_url, bnb_url, xrp_url, ada_url]
my_dfs = []

for url in my_urls:
    my_dfs.append(create_df(url))
```